# Getting ORA-01427 trying to select all from view I've created

Tags: oracle

I created a view from tables using these queries

```
CREATE VIEW AVAIL_TOOLS AS
SELECT T.TOOL_NAME AS "Name", R.RETAILER_NAME AS "Retailer", T.RETAILER_NUM AS "Number", I.TI_STATUS AS "Status",
(SELECT 
  CASE 
     WHEN DETAIL_RETURNDATE IS NULL THEN TO_CHAR(DETAIL_DUEDATE,'Day, Month, DD, YYYY') 
     ELSE 'Now' END FROM DETAILRENTAL) AS "Expected Avaliablity"  
FROM TOOL T
INNER JOIN RETAILER R
ON T.RETAILER_NUM = R.RETAILER_NUM
INNER JOIN TOOLINSTANCE I
ON T.TOOL_NUM = I.TOOL_NUM
WHERE (I.TI_STATUS = 'Rented') OR (I.TI_STATUS = 'Available')
ORDER BY T.TOOL_NAME;
```

now when I try to run SELECT * FROM AVAIL_TOOLS
I receive the error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.
The case I am running in the query obviously seems to be the problem. Now is there anyway I could change the queries around. I am trying to create a view where if the return date is null it will be available when it is returned other wise it should be now.

I'm at a loss on how I should change about to get the resulted needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query below should do what you want when you fill proper join condition.

```
CREATE VIEW AVAIL_TOOLS AS
SELECT T.TOOL_NAME AS "Name", R.RETAILER_NAME AS "Retailer", T.RETAILER_NUM AS "Number", I.TI_STATUS AS "Status", 
  CASE 
     WHEN DETAIL_RETURNDATE IS NULL THEN TO_CHAR(DETAIL_DUEDATE,'Day, Month, DD, YYYY') 
     ELSE 'Now' END "Expected Avaliablity"  
FROM TOOL T
INNER JOIN RETAILER R
ON T.RETAILER_NUM = R.RETAILER_NUM
INNER JOIN TOOLINSTANCE I
ON T.TOOL_NUM = I.TOOL_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN DETAILRENTAL DR
ON (I.ID? = DR.TOOL_INSTANCE_ID?) --HERE fill join
WHERE (I.TI_STATUS = 'Rented') OR (I.TI_STATUS = 'Available')
ORDER BY T.TOOL_NAME;
```

Second option is adding to subquery with case where clause based on the same condition as join:

```
where I.INSTANCE_ID = DETAILRENTAL.INSTANCE_ID
```

Comment: it works out after i added the left join, but it seems to repeat some items and add items that shouldn't be in there. But my question regarding the case has been solved. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are combining the result of that `CASE` expression for ALL rows in `DETAILRENTAL` with ALL the rows from the three-table join. Instead, you probably only want the "expected availability" for the specific tool in the main `SELECT`. You could fix it by making the subquery into a correlated subquery; but it makes more sense to just have the `CASE` expression as a column in the outer `SELECT`, not wrapped within a subquery, and to add a join to `DETAILRENTAL` on whatever you need to join on (probably `TOOL_NUM`?)